# Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -9

Tags: python, macos, selenium, web-scraping

I am having so many problems with the `webdriver` for webscraping with selemium. The `chromedriver` is already installed and placed in the same folder as python file. All the suggestions that seem to load the the jupyter cell  for few seconds are rejected after to this following message: `chromedriver cannot opened because the developer cannot be verififed` where I used `homebrew` to download them. Here my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver

my_url='google.com'
driver= webdriver.Chrome()
```

I am now trying to solve this problem by downloading chromium but I have that `status code was 9` error and that pop up telling me that my code cannot be trusted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

/usr/local/bin/chromedriver replace with actual path

Answer (score 2):

While using selenium's [webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager),  we had this same error from this line

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())`

To fix it, we opened a chrome window -> settings -> about chrome -> update chrome. Or `chrome://settings/help` on your browser.

After it finished building the new version of chrome, that same line no longer generates the error.

Of course, this only worked since Google had pushed a new version of chrome with a bugfix for whatever was causing that.

Answer (score 1):

*chromedriver is being block; and to unblock enter:*

`xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /opt/homebrew/bin/chromedriver`

> '/opt/homebrew/bin/chromedriver'  should be replaced by the path to the  chromedriver in use on your machine.

*To find the chromedriver being, enter:* 
`which chromedriver`

This resource may be helpful. It adds detail to [PDHide](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6793637/pdhide)'s post.
[Chromedriver can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69315805/chromedriver-can-t-be-opened-because-apple-cannot-check-it-for-malicious-softwar)

Answer (score 0):

If this occurs on a Mac, open up activity monitor, do a search for "chrome" and force quit everything that comes up. In my case, I had 20+ chrome driver  functions running (I used reuse_driver=True but did not "close()" everything after a bad run) I also think you can run "python -m botasaurus.close"